# Comment comprendre l'usage du passé simple et de l'imparfait ici ?

Tags: imparfait

Bonjour,

Dans *Une saison en enfer* :

> J'inventai la couleur des voyelles ! - A noir, E blanc, I rouge, O
> bleu, U vert. - Je réglai la forme et le mouvement de chaque consonne,
> et, avec des rythmes instinctifs, je me flattai d'inventer un verbe
> poétique accessible, un jour ou l'autre, à tous les sens. Je réservais
> la traduction.
>
> Ce fut d'abord une étude. J'écrivais des silences, des nuits, je
> notais l'inexprimable. Je fixais des vertiges.

Pourquoi Rimbaud passe ici du passé simplé (inventai ; réglai ; flattai) à l'imparfait (réservais ; écrivais ; notais ; fixais) ?

Comment: Lorsque l'inspiration survient, lorsque tous les sens sont en éveil pour savourer cet instant, son empreinte reste comme une révélation : *cela s'est passé* ainsi et cela perdure dans chacune de mes cellules sensitives. Ensuite, une fois que le récit de cette expérience est écrit, il est terminé, une relecture sera nécessaire pour faire revivre ces sensations, elles ont été *imparfaitement transcrites en mots*

Comment: @Personne Alors l'imparfait parachève ?

Comment: @LPH — Non, il indique que l'action passée n'a pas de répercussion dans le présent, sans qu'il y ait de notion de projet réalisé, de qualité supérieure à une autre (la racine sanskrite *para-* est liée à la notion de suprême, ultime, indépassable, …). L'action est terminée, elle a été ce qu'elle fut. Point (point d'autre mot à ajouter pour signifier quoique ce soit, le mental se tait)

Answer (score 4):

À mon avis, le changement vers l'imparfait après une suite de passé simples montre qu'il ne s'agit plus d'une action bien délimité dans le passé, comme les précédentes le sont (inventai, réglai, …), mais d'action qui durent ou se répètent depuis  la première de ces actions passées. C'est à dire que, par exemple (mais cela il ne l'explique pas et on peut seulement le supposer) quand il inventa la couleur des voyelles et aussi quand il régla la forme et le mouvement de chaque consonne, etc., en faisant cela, il réservait aussi une traduction, en faisant cela il notait aussi l'inexprimable.

Answer (score 2):

On ne peut pas lire ces lignes sans les replacer dans le contexte global de *L'alchimie du verbe*<sup>1</sup>. Ces lignes se situent au début de *Délires II*,<sup>2</sup> et c'est tout au long des 5 pages que Rimbaud oscille entre imparfait et passé simple (sauf les passages en vers qui sont presque entièrement au présent) avec une dernière phrase au présent.

> Rimbaud utilise l'imparfait et le passé simple pour bien préciser qu'il s'agit d'une expérience poétique révolue, qu'il cherche à oublier; à la fin du texte Rimbaud semble donc dire définitivement « Adieu » ( « Cela s'est passé. Je sais aujourd’hui saluer la beauté »)<sup>3</sup>.

Pour comprendre *L'alchimie du verbe* il faut aussi avoir en tête que dans *Délires II* Rimbaud évoque sa folie, les parties qui suivent montrent un retour à la raison. Dans « *Alchimie du Verbe*  Rimbaud raconte son aventure littéraire<sup>4</sup> ». Il ne faut pas chercher d'explication grammaticale à ces passages constants entre l'imparfait et le passé simple, mais considérer qu'on est dans la pensée décousue du poète, dans sa folie qui n'obéit à aucune règle. Sinon comment expliquer l'emploi dans une même phrase du passé simple et de l’imparfait, comme celle-ci par exemple :

> Je m'habituai à l'hallucination simple : je voyais très franchement une mosquée à la place d'une usine, ...

Deux citations à l'appui :

> Rimbaud avoue dans *Alchimie du verbe*, avoir malmené la langue. Il passe en revue ses forfaits<sup>5</sup>.

> « Les premiers paragraphes évoquent rapidement les étapes qui le menèrent à la crise décisive. Il commence par se détacher des routines de la poésie contemporaine, et par créer en lui-même un monde d'images entièrement libérées<sup>6</sup>. »

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> 5<sup>e</sup> partie de *Une saison en enfer*.</sup> 
<sup><sup>2</sup> [Texte complet](http://abardel.free.fr/tout_rimbaud/une_saison_en_enfer.htm#delires_2).</sup>  
<sup><sup>3</sup> [Commentaire de texte](http://profmireille.over-blog.com/article-a-rimbaud-alchimie-du-verbe-1873-96624029.html) d'un professeur de français.</sup>
<sup><sup>4</sup> *Rimbaud créateur*, Jean-Pierre Giusto (PUF, 1980)</sup> 
<sup><sup>5</sup> [Sylvain Tesson](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvain_Tesson) [sur France Inter](https://www.franceinter.fr/emissions/un-ete-avec-rimbaud/un-ete-avec-rimbaud-03-aout-2020)</sup>
<sup><sup>6</sup>  Rimbaud, œuvres complètes, édition La Pléiade, annotée par Antoine Adam.</sup>

Comment: Merci. D'un point de vue strictement temporel, l'imparfait ne marque pas ici l'habitude ?

Comment: Le mot *folie* est un polysème dont l'éventail dont la lecture des contraires dans Le petit Pobert est ahurissante, parmi ceux-ci, *déraison* semble le plus approprié ici : sortir des limites de la raison, celle « des braves gens qui n'aime pas que l'on suive une autre route qu'eux… » ne fait pas de vous un psychopathe, un monstre, un dément, seulement quelqu'un qui va au-delà des limites sociales usuelles, ce qu'entre autres aventures vécues, signe la liberté profonde de Rimbaud (qui se traduit dans “l'écornage” [néologisme assumé :-) ] des règles grammaticales ici), et non son aliénation. …

Comment: …  Il a pu se dire fou comme don Quichotte … pour qu'on lui fiche la paix ! … ce qui n'est pas une folle pratique.

Comment: @ovide  À mon avis certainement pas l'habitude. *Le bon usage* a  4 pages sur les valeurs de l'imparfait, on pourrait appliquer certaines à ce passage (narratif/historique ;  de tentative : marquer un procès inachevé qu'on a tenté, c'est celui vers lequel je pencherais si on m'obligeait à donner une valeur)

Comment: @ovide mais je pense qu'il ne faut rien y voir d'autres que l'expression d'actions achevées, valeur commune avec le passé simple. Sinon comment expliquer « Je m'habituai à l'hallucination simple : je voyais très franchement une mosquée à la place d'une usine » ou « je m'habituai » est au passé simple et « je voyais » à l'imparfait ; c'est à dire juste le contraire de ce qu'on aurait attendu si on voulait mettre ça dans des cases « traditionnelles ».

Comment: @None Merci beaucoup !

Comment: @None — « Je *m'habituai* à l'hallucination simple : *je voyais* très franchement une mosquée à la place d'une usine » peut être compris, dans le respect des temps : « Je *m'habituai à* [au principe/à la venue/…] d'hallucination simple (qui furent mon pain quotidien/au cours de cette période) : [durant lesquelles] *je voyais* très franchement une mosquée à la place d'une usine [et une autre fois autre chose, qui changeait à chaque hallucination …] »  …

Comment: … c'est une forme de licence poétique qui permet de dépasser les limites des conventions grammaticales pour leur faire exprimer la densité des émotions/intuitions/révélations spontanées, seule l'apparence se craquelle, mais les bases sont “saines”, ou en tout cas cohérentes.

Comment: Je crois que habituai/voyais s'explique assez facilement, on comprend qu'il a finit par s'habituer, le passé simple marquant la réalisation, et pendant une certaine période de temps, avant et/ou après son adaptation, il voyait les choses d'une certaine façon. C'est très élégant, je ne pourrais le qualifier de "folie sans règle".

Answer (score 0):

Le passé simple est devenu, au contraire de l'italien (!), depuis environ 200 ans (après la Révolution de 1789) une pure forme littéraire de la forme écrite d'un évènement révolu, entièrement terminé, délimité souvent par des indications de date précise (''Il fut battu en 1850'') tandis que la forme de l'imparfait, c'est de la narration à tout va, très populaire aussi dans le langage courant (''Hier, je n'étais pas à la maison'') même plus commode que le passe composé (Hier, j'ai  é t é ....à la maison'' > ici pour donner plus de poids, d'emphase au dire ....''d'avoir été à la maison et pas ailleurs''.) D'ailleurs ''ai été'' et ''étais'' sont, parlés, très proches dans la prononciation; je soupçonne donc que l'imparfait s'est construit, petit à petit, à partir du passé composé. // Je connais une exception sensationnelle  avec le verbe ''naître'' où l'on utilise l'imparfait malgré l'indication d'une date précise, soit dans le cas de l'autre signification de ''germer, pousser, prospérer''; ex.: (entendu à la télé) ''La Croix Rouge naissait en 1863'', c-à-d. elle naquit bien cette année précise, mais ''naître'' continua sa vie en adoptant autre acception de ''prospérer'' jusqu'à nos jours. C'est vraiment un cas linguistique exceptionel car, d'habitude, l'indication d'une date dans le passé révolu entraîne/exige l'emploi du passé simple. // Bref: Le passé simple = l'action en cours d'achèvement ou terminée il y peu > qch a été fait activement tandis que l'imparfait, c'est le simple constat sans émotion de cette action (Il fut tué = on le tua <> il était (donc) tué, = mort quoi) // (12.12.21)

Comment: "je soupçonne donc que l'imparfait s'est construit, petit à petit, à partir du passé composé" : si vraiment ce n'est pas de la pure spéculation, il faut donner des références. Il me semble que l'imparfait est bien plus ancien que le passé composé. En attendant voici mes références accessibles en ligne : [L'histoire de l'imparfait](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/imparfait.html) et dans [cet article](https://perso.atilf.fr/apotheloz/wp-content/uploads/sites/59/2015/06/Cahiers_Chron_28.pdf) voir le  §  *Histoire du passé composé*.